# Python - Compute frequency of unique elements

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, python-imaging-library

I have a bunch of unique RGB colors in a dictionary in a `key: 'Color'` and a `list` of every RGB color in a target image.

I want to:

- Iterate over the Target RGB color list
- Check if that element matches any of the colors in the `key: 'Color'`
- If it matches I want to change the `key: frequency` to increase it by one (+= 1)

In the end I hope to achieve to update `frequency['Frequency']` so at the end of the process `dict: Frequency` will contain a bunch of pairs of `(Color,Frequency)`. I then want to sort from lower to higher frequency and print each pair of RGB Color + number of appearances.

Here's my code so far:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('test.png').convert('RGB')
im2 = Image.open('test2.png').convert('RGB')

unique_colors = set()

def get_unique_colors(img):
    for i in range(0,img.size[0]):
        for j in range(0,img.size[1]):
            r,g,b = img.getpixel((i,j))
            unique_colors.add((r,g,b))
    return(unique_colors)

unique_colors = get_unique_colors(im)

all_colors = []

def get_all_colors(img):
    for i in range(0,img.size[0]):
        for j in range(0,img.size[1]):
            r,g,b = rgb_im.getpixel((i,j))
            all_colors.append((r,g,b))
    return(all_colors)

all_colors = get_all_colors(im2)

frequency = {'Color': list(unique_colors), 'Frequency': [0 for x in range(0,len(unique_colors))]}
```

I'm facing many issues with my lack of ability to manipulate dictionaries, is it really appropriate to use dictionaries to store such data in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your dictionary creation is incorrect. You can have a dict(color, frequency) structure if you create your `dict` like the following:

```
frequency = dict(zip(list(unique_colors), [0 for x in range(0,len(unique_colors))]))
```

The `zip` function puts the two lists together as the key and value pairs. If `unique_colors={'red','green','blue'}`, this will create a dictionary like:

```
frequency = {'red': 0, 'green': 0, 'blue': 0}
```

Afterwards you can update the dictionary as:

```
frequency['red']+=1
```

And the dict becomes `{'red': 1, 'green': 0, 'blue': 0}`

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot.
After that I only had to do:
`for e in all_colors:
    for i in unique_colors:
        if e == i:
            frequency[e] += 1`

And than each (R,G,B) tuple would have its counter updated.

Comment: Glad to be able to help!

Answer (score 0):

Using dictionaries is a great idea and it turns out the standard lib has done some of the work for you with `collections.Counter` which counts things you put into it. Add `itertools.product` to run through all pixel locations and toss that into a custom pixel iterator and you get

```
from PIL import Image
import collections
import itertools

def iter_colors(img):
    coordinates = itertools.product(range(img.size[0]), range(img.size[1]))
    return map(img.getpixel, coordinates)

im = Image.open('test.png').convert('RGB')
im2 = Image.open('test2.png').convert('RGB')

unique_colors = set(iter_colors(im))
print("unique", unique_colors)

frequencies = collections.Counter((rgb for rgb in iter_colors(im2)
    if rgb in unique_colors))
print("frequencies", frequencies)

# counter keys are rgb tuples and velue is number of times seen
rgbs_sorted = list(sorted(frequencies))
print("im2 rgb values sorted by value:", ", ".join(
    str(rgb) for rgb in rgbs_sorted))
print("im2 rgb values sorted by most common:", ", ".join(
    str(rgb) for rgb in frequencies.most_common()))
print("one rgb value", frequencies[rgbs_sorted[0]])
```

On a test image, this returned

```
unique {(0, 0, 255), (191, 191, 191), (0, 255, 0)}
frequencies Counter({(191, 191, 191): 45, (0, 0, 255): 44, (0, 255, 0): 32})
im2 rgb values sorted by value: (0, 0, 255), (0, 255, 0), (191, 191, 191)
im2 rgb values sorted by most common: ((191, 191, 191), 45), ((0, 0, 255), 44), ((0, 255, 0), 32)
one rgb value 44
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, very short script and it works. The only problem is that I'm not sure how can I retrieve specific RGB Colors and its values from this data structure.

Comment: They work much like dicts (see docs at https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). I've added some samples.